# How do I avoid Cross origin requests issues when doing POST with JQuery (and Sinatra)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js, sinatra

I have a HTML + KnockoutJS + JQuery site deployed under Apache on my machine, accesible at `http://daily/admin.html` (or `http://localhost/admin.html`). The backend is built in Sinatra and runs under rackup, so I can access its API at `http://localhost:9292/api/items`
The problem is that if I do an AJAX GET request, I get:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9292/api/items. Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

My fix was to add the following line to the Sinatra app:

```
headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 'http://daily'
```

Problem is that now I cannot do a POST using Ajax. I got the following message:

```
Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.
```

Is JSONP an option? Can I use JSONP for POST?

Comment: The error messages kind of confuses me. Are you using HTTPS?

Comment: Nope, it's the Same Origin Policy, I guess

Comment: It's the "only for HTTP" that confuses me. Because, well, what else should be supported? Of course it's HTTP, cause that's what the browser is talking... => Weird error message.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSONP for this case.

With this code above, I think you miss something

```
headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS'
```

Comment: Hm, so POST should work with JSONP? I have to try it. On the other hand, I have to think about how to deploy it so I won't have this problem. Don't wanna use Sinatra templates..